# Dynamically create columns sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I have a table of Customers

```
Customer ID        Name         
   1               John        
   2               Lewis        
   3               Mary
```

I have another table CustomerRewards

```
 TypeID           Description
   1                Bronze
   2                Silver
   3                Gold
   4               Platinum
   5               AnotherOne
```

And the final table

```
 RewardID          TypeID          CustomerID
    1                1                 1
    2                1                 1
    3                2                 1
    4                2                 2
```

The customerTypes table is dynamic, many of these types can be added and removed. Basically all I want is the columns to be generated dynamically and a count in each, something like

```
CustomerName        Bronze        Silver     Gold      Platinum     AnotherOne    total
   John               2             1         0           0             0           3
   Lewis              0             1         0           0             0           1
 Grand TOTAL          2             2         0           0             0           4
```

The problem like I said it that the types are dynamic and the customers are dynamic so I need the columns to be dynamic depending on the types in the system

I have tagged c# as I need this in a DataGridView

Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like a pivot. I've done a few, but I can't type one up from memory. Maybe a a view in the DB created from pivoting the data on the SQL side?

Comment: You probably want dynamic pivot, if you need to do this in SQL. See, e.g., http://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2007/09/14/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005/ But that's not really a clean solution. If you can wait to get your data into C#, you could use LINQ to do this.

Comment: These do look complex! thanks for the comments, I will look into Pivot but if anyone has an easy solution please feel free

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You will want to use a `PIVOT` function for this.  If you have a known number of columns, then you can hard-code the values:

```
select name, [Bronze], [Silver], [Gold], [Platinum], [AnotherOne]
from
(
  select c.name,
    cr.description,
    r.typeid
  from customers c
  left join rewards r
    on c.id = r.customerid
  left join customerrewards cr
    on r.typeid = cr.typeid
) x
pivot
(
  count(typeid)
  for description in ([Bronze], [Silver], [Gold], [Platinum], [AnotherOne])
) p;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25d14/10).

Now if you have an unknown number of columns, then you can use dynamic SQL to `PIVOT`:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(description) 
                    from customerrewards
                    group by description, typeid
                    order by typeid
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT name,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select c.name,
                  cr.description,
                  r.typeid
                from customers c
                left join rewards r
                  on c.id = r.customerid
                left join customerrewards cr
                  on r.typeid = cr.typeid
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(typeid)
                for description in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25d14/9)

If you need to include the `Total` column, then you can use `ROLLUP` ([Static Version Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25d14/14)):

```
select name, sum([Bronze]) Bronze, sum([Silver]) Silver, 
  sum([Gold]) Gold, sum([Platinum]) Platinum, sum([AnotherOne]) AnotherOne
from 
(
  select name, [Bronze], [Silver], [Gold], [Platinum], [AnotherOne]
  from
  (
    select c.name,
      cr.description,
      r.typeid
    from customers c
    left join rewards r
      on c.id = r.customerid
    left join customerrewards cr
      on r.typeid = cr.typeid
  ) x
  pivot
  (
    count(typeid)
    for description in ([Bronze], [Silver], [Gold], [Platinum], [AnotherOne])
  ) p
) x
group by name with rollup
```

Dynamic version ([Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25d14/17)):

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsRollup AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(description) 
                    from customerrewards
                    group by description, typeid
                    order by typeid
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsRollup 
      = STUFF((SELECT ', Sum(' + QUOTENAME(description) + ') as '+ QUOTENAME(description)
                    from customerrewards
                    group by description, typeid
                    order by typeid
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query 
          = 'SELECT name, '+ @colsRollup + '
             FROM
             (
                SELECT name,' + @cols + ' from 
                 (
                    select c.name,
                      cr.description,
                      r.typeid
                    from customers c
                    left join rewards r
                      on c.id = r.customerid
                    left join customerrewards cr
                      on r.typeid = cr.typeid
                ) x
                pivot 
                (
                    count(typeid)
                    for description in (' + @cols + ')
                ) p 
              ) x1
              GROUP BY name with ROLLUP'

execute(@query)
```

Comment: You have one SQL Injection flaw / usability bug: 
= STUFF((SELECT ', Sum(' + QUOTENAME(description) + ') as '+ description

Should be:
 = STUFF((SELECT ', Sum(' + QUOTENAME(description) + ') as '+ QUOTENAME(description)

Otherwise, that is an awesome post!

Comment: @shellster Yup, you are right. I updated my code. Thanks for catching that.