# Dynamically add columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a variable in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
```

Variable `@cols` contains these values:

```
[Afghanistan],[Australia],[Bangladesh]
```

Somewhere in a stored procedure, I have this SQL statement:

```
SELECT ID, AccountTypeName AS Type 
FROM cte AS t
```

I want this SQL satement to execute with the column names stored in `@cols` -
like this

```
SELECT ID, AccountTypeName, [Afghanistan], [Australia], [Bangladesh],[England] AS Type 
FROM cte AS t
```

My problem is I am using a CTE.

Comment: You can do it olny using dynamic sql; cte should be defined inside this dynamic code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically create columns sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643117/dynamically-create-columns-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic T-SQL statement:

```
DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT ID,AccountTypeName, ' + @cols + ' as Type from cte as t'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement
```

Answer (score 0):

However use `Print` command to check what Query looks

Complete Dynamic `T-SQL` Query Approach is here

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @Query NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = '[Afghanistan],[Australia],[Bangladesh]';

SET @Query = N';WITH CTE AS (SELECT NULL [DATA]) SELECT [DATA], '+@cols+' FROM CTE';

PRINT @Query;

EXEC sp_executesql @Query;
```

How could u bound the column which is not part of `CTE` ? & why ?

Other way

However you could bind the Dynamic column directly in `CTE` as below :

```
SET @cols = 'NULL [Afghanistan],NULL [Australia],NULL [Bangladesh]';

SET @Query = N';WITH CTE AS (SELECT NULL [DATA], '+@cols+') SELECT * FROM CTE';
```

@Query result :

```
;WITH CTE AS (SELECT NULL [DATA], NULL [Afghanistan],NULL [Australia],NULL [Bangladesh]) SELECT * FROM CTE
```

EXEC sp_executesql @Query result :

```
DATA    Afghanistan Australia   Bangladesh
NULL    NULL        NULL        NULL
```