# How do I aggregate data into multiple different summed columns by criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

I have data that looks like this:

```
| DateTime         | Category | Total |
|------------------|----------|-------|
| 3/23/18 9:00 AM  | Bork     | 1     |
| 3/23/18 9:15 AM  | Arf      | 2     |
| 3/23/18 9:30 AM  | Bork     | 1     |
| 3/23/18 9:45 AM  | Arf      | 2     |
| 3/23/18 10:00 AM | Bork     | 1     |
| 3/23/18 10:15 AM | Arf      | 2     |
| 3/23/18 10:30 AM | Bork     | 1     |
| 3/23/18 10:45 AM | Arf      | 2     |
| 3/23/18 11:00 AM | Bork     | 1     |
| 3/23/18 11:15 AM | Arf      | 2     |
| 3/23/18 11:30 AM | Bork     | 1     |
| 3/23/18 11:45 AM | Arf      | 2     |
| 3/23/18 12:00 PM | Bork     | 1     |
| 3/23/18 12:15 PM | Arf      | 2     |
| 3/23/18 12:30 PM | Bork     | 1     |
| 3/23/18 12:45 PM | Arf      | 2     |
```

And I want to sum by hour and keep the categories separate like this:

```
| Hour | Borks | Arfs |
|------|-------|------|
| 9    | 2     | 4    |
| 10   | 2     | 4    |
| 11   | 2     | 4    |
| 12   | 2     | 4    |
```

I know how to sum data by hour already... I use a query like this:

```
SELECT DatePart("h", DateTime), SUM(Total)
FROM Events
GROUP BY DatePart("h", DateTime), DateAdd("d", 0, DateDiff("d", 0, DateTime))
```

But how do I sum the categories into separate columns, and how do I name the columns in the output too?

Also, how do I make sure all hours are represented in the results, even if they have no data in the source? For example, it would have the hour listed and the total = 0.

Comment: Please tag your DBMS (version included)

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Use case expressions in the select list to do conditional aggregation.

Comment: If you DO KNOW the number of columns before running the script, that may be easy. Otherwise that can be a bit tough... Check [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12643408/8242325) answer. And please specify if you are using SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc..

Comment: @BrunoMiquelin `DATEPART` is almost certainly SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a pivot on the category:

```
SELECT
    DatePart(hour, DateTime),
    SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Bork' THEN Total ELSE 0 END) AS Borks,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Arf'  THEN Total ELSE 0 END) AS Arfs
FROM Events
GROUP BY DatePart(hour, DateTime)
ORDER BY MIN(DateTime);
```

Note also that you current `GROUP BY` may not be what you intend.  If you want to report hour groups, then group only by hours.

Comment: Works only in case he have ONLY those 2 categories.  
I guess he wants a dynamic query option

Comment: @BrunoMiquelin Did the OP indicate that there might be other categories?

Comment: @BrunoMiquelin If OP wants to do that dynamically, he can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18657579/2500920), he might get some idea about dynamic PIVOT.